# Differential calculus: quotient rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is an exercise from Khan Academy, using the quotient rule. What are the steps for finding the derivative of this function:
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)-\sqrt{x}\cos(x) }{2\sqrt{x}\sin^2(x)}$$

To this: In the next part a "$2x$" appears replacing "$\sqrt{x}$" in the numerator. What is the step there?
$$\frac{\sin(x)-2x\cos(x)}{2\sqrt{x}\sin^2(x)}$$

Comment: Please link the video.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the next part?"  The two expressions are not equal.  What do they say they've done to go from the first to the second?

Comment: it seems just a mistake

Comment: There probably is not a mistake in the video, it's just that the question isn't referencing the material correctly.

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-derivative-rules/ab-quotient-rule/e/differentiate-quotients Not sure if he is referring to the problem here or not?

Comment: The original function was $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sin(x)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I see where you are talking about.
He has $\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\cdot \sin(x)-\sqrt{x} \cdot \cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}$

To clean this up. He multiplies top and bottom by $2 \sqrt{x}$ giving:

$\frac{\color{red}{2 \sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\cdot \sin(x)-\color{red}{2 \sqrt{x}}\sqrt{x} \cdot \cos(x)}{\color{red}{2 \sqrt{x}}\sin^2(x)}$

Doing a little simplifying gives:

$\frac{ \sin(x)-2 x \cos(x)}{ 2 \sqrt{x} \sin^2(x)}$

The following is a print screen of khan's site:
[image]